# How to use two svelte componenets on different pages with distinct ids?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I'd like to use two unrelated svelte compoents on two distincpages of a website say  `/cats` and `/dogs` so in `main.js` I have

```
import App from './App.svelte'; //this is empty

import ListCats from './ListCats.svelte';

import ListDogs from './ListDogs.svelte';
 
new ListCats({
  target: document.querySelector('#list-cats'),
});

new ListDogs({
  target: document.querySelector('#list-dogs'),
});

const app = new App({
    target: document.body    
});

export default app;
```

The prblem is that error:

```
Uncaught Error: 'target' is a required option
    at new SvelteComponentDev (index.mjs:1993:19)
    at new ListDogs (ListDogs.svelte:76:39)
    at main.js:9:1
    at main.js:24:2
```

This arises becasue `/cats` page does not have `#list-dogs` and `/dogs` does not have `#list-cats` and both pages import the same bundle.js of svelte.

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: so, have you considered using an `if` statement?

Comment: I though about that but not sure where should I use if, as I'm total noob to svelte.

Comment: hows your javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
let target = document.querySelector('#list-cats');
if (target) new ListCats({ target });

target = document.querySelector('#list-dogs');
if (target) new ListDogs({ target });
```

Comment: Brilliant. This resolves the problem. Thanks!